# Displaying Random Image from ACF Options Page

Tags: plugins, custom-field

So I've been tasked with making an "Image Advert" to be placed on a sidebar on this website. The client wants to have the ability to upload 5 images on to the ACF Options Page and then have a random image be pulled from there and displayed on the sidebar at random everytime the page refreshes.

I was wondering if it was possible for anyone to help me.

```
<?php 
    $rows = get_field('image_advert_repeater'); // get all the rows
    $rand_row = $rows[ array_rand($rows, 1) ]; // get a random row
    $rand_row_image = $rand_row['image_advert_images']; // get the sub field value 
    // Note
    // $first_row_image = 123 (image ID)
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $rand_row_image, 'full' );
    // url = $image[0];
    // width = $image[1];
    // height = $image[2];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

This is the code I'm currently trying to use to display the images. It's taken from the ACF Repeater documentation and I've editied it to use my repeater but I can't seem to get it to work. I've also tried adding 'options' to the end of the field names to see if that's the isssue but it just white screens the website on refresh.

Comment: Set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in your `wp-config.php` - sounds like you're getting a fatal error somewhere, this will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Ah! I've just done that now and I'm getting an error! "Warning: array_rand() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/starkers-master/front-page.php on line 40" Thank you, hopefully from this I'll be able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed the issue - since your ACF field is an options page, you need to pass the second argument `options` to `get_field` - add a bit of sanity checking too:

```
$rows = get_field( 'image_advert_repeater', 'options' );
if ( ! empty( $rows ) && is_array( $rows ) ) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I've tried that and it's not seemed to have worked. I'll have to have a little play around and see where I'm going wrong. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
<?php $rows = get_field( 'image_advert_repeater', 'options' );
// Wrap in an if statement to prevent an empy image SRC if no rows exist
if ( ! empty( $rows ) && is_array( $rows ) ) {
    // Get the row and ranomise
    $rand_row = $rows[ array_rand($rows) ];
    // get the image url from the array
    $rand_row_image = $rand_row['image_advert_images'];
    // make things easier to read
    $image = $rand_row_image;
?>
<!-- Echo out the image -->
<img src="<?php echo $image ?>" />
```